# Windows 10 UWP : Unable to stop Looping of Pivot Control

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I am trying to stop looping of Pivot Control in my Windows 10 UWP application.
I am no where found any solution for that.

Anyone have any idea about this to stop looping pivot control.

Also i want to stop direct navigation.
Suppose, we are having 6 Pivot Items in my pivot and I don't want to jump directly to Pivot Item 1 to Pivot Item 4. It should be step forward process i.e Pivotitem 1 to PivotItem 2 or PivotItem 2 to PivotItem 3.

I tried to do on selection Changed Event of Pivot Control but it didn't works for me.

```
var currentPivot = ((Pivot)sender);
var count = e.AddedItems.Count;

if ((currentPivot.SelectedIndex) > count)
{
    Pager.SelectedIndex = count - 1;
}
```

Any response would be appreciated !

Comment: I think You can't. You can use FlipView or a horizontal ListView but you would need to recreate the pivot headers by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with SDK 14393, Win10 1607, this it now possible:

```
<Pivot IsHeaderItemsCarouselEnabled="False"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have looping behavior you can just use FlipView and change it style to looks like pivot.

Comment: can't we achieve through pivot control ?

Comment: I don't know any way that will let you do it in pivot.

Answer (score 0):

I've did this in this way:

1. Change pivot ManipulationMode `ManipulationMode="TranslateX"`
2. Add ManipulationDelta and ManipulationCompleted handlers

My pivot now looks like:

```
<Pivot ManipulationMode="TranslateX" x:Name="testPivot" ManipulationDelta="testPivot_ManipulationDelta" ManipulationCompleted="testPivot_ManipulationCompleted">
    <PivotItem Header="Page1" ></PivotItem>
    <PivotItem  Header="Page2"></PivotItem>
    <PivotItem  Header="Page3"></PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

3. Implement handlers.

Mine look so:

```
double xDelta = 0;
private void testPivot_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    xDelta += e.Delta.Translation.X;
}

private void testPivot_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(xDelta > 0)
    {

        if (testPivot.SelectedIndex > 0)
            testPivot.SelectedIndex--;
    }
    else
    {
        if(xDelta < 0)
            if (testPivot.SelectedIndex < testPivot.Items.Count() - 1)
                testPivot.SelectedIndex++;

    }
    xDelta = 0;
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

4. Now you may want to add some animation between pivot items changes or do some other adjustments

Comment: I tried but didn't work. event handler are not invoking. It still looping the pivot items.

Comment: I've created a simple example for you on github that shows how it works: https://github.com/bl00dra1n/PivotExample

Comment: Yes, I tried and run your application. It didn't work. I am still able to loop the pivot item..

Answer (score 0):

use this code. I'm hoping that this is help full logic for needed.

Here Constructor of page:

```
    public PagePivot()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            pivot.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(pivot_SelectionChanged); 
        }
```

Event listener of pivot selection changed:

```
 if (pivot.SelectedIndex == 0 && previousSelectedIndex == <number Of screens - 1>)
            pivot.SelectedIndex = <number Of screens - 1>;
        previousSelectedIndex = pivot.SelectedIndex;
```